# Decomposition through thermolysis, electrolysis, photolysis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

What decides whether a compound will dissociate (break-up) under thermal decomposition or photolysis or electrolysis i.e if I am provided with a compound and I'm asked to dissociate it then how will I get to know that it would dissociate under thermal decomposition or photolysis or electrolysis.

Please try to provide an easy-to-understand as I'm in just 10th grade

Comment: The most general answer is that every compound will breakup if enough energy can be added to it.  In a simple diatomic thermal energy will increase the vibrational (and rotational) energy until the bonds breaks. Electromagnetic radiation (uv, vis , ir) can also do this, as well as forming excited electronic states that  decompose.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should analyse the chemical bindings in your compound, e.g. ion bindings will easily break-up in water, stronger bindings may require You to use heating or electric current to dissociate the molecule. Also if you know the structure of the compound, look for some similar structures on the internet, the more similar the structures, the more similar properties they have, so similar factors will dissociate them.